# (swift) update a number to label will make the view get back to original position

Tags: swift

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrPOH.gif)

When I update a number to label will make the view get back to original position.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var aview: UIView!

var number = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func plus(sender: UIButton) {
    number++
    label.text = "number：\(number)"

}

@IBAction func move(sender: AnyObject) {
    aview.frame.origin.y -= 20
}
```

}

I couldn't find the answer on web, please help me to fix this problem.Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you use autolayout?

Comment: I think not, i just drag button label and view to the screen,didn't set any constraints.

Comment: Can you  show xib or storyboard you config for all this item?

Comment: I record a video for this yesterday, check it on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF5_cxQYkl8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your xib or Storyboard you set use Autolayout:

So if you don't set constrain system will auto generate it. When you change frame by set frame it effect but when you access to it. It will auto back to old position.

if you don't want it happen. You set in viewDidLoad:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: In swift, the code should be like    self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

Comment: @AlbertTeslaYe I write this code in swift 2.  It is still right :)

Comment: I set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, than the size of my view became very small, width : 376 hight 144,did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Because no constraint, view will keep same size with on xib or storyboard. You should add constraint for it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is probably related to a constraint reloading when the label reloads. 
Instead of setting `aview.frame.origin.y -= 20` you should make an outlet to the constraint holding the y position of your aView and then update the constant of that constraint outlet instead.

Comment: it just like before, nothing change, it still go back

Comment: Could you tell me how to make an outlet to the constraint holding the y position?

Comment: If my guess is correct you already have some constraint that holds the y position in some way. Check in the interface builder and see what constrains are connected the the view. If you find something controlling the y position in some way you can create an outlet for it by Ctrl-dragging the outlet out in your code just like you can for any view.

Comment: I can't find any constraint, Could you try to recreate this code to see what happened? Thanks!